# Wrong comment position using AJAX and JQUERY and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-5.1.6

I'm creating a "without refresh page comment" using Jquery and Ajax.

Inside **posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @post.title %>
<%= @post.body %>
<%= render 'comment %>
```

**posts/_comment.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Add Comment", new_post_comment_path(@post), id: "new_comment", remote: true %>

<div id="comments">
    <%= nested_comments @post.comments.arrange(:order => "created_at DESC") %>
</div>
```

**comments.controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="comment_form">
    <%= simple_form_for [@post, @comment], remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit "Confirm"  %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**comments/new.js.erb**

```
$('#new_comment').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

**comments/create.js.erb**

```
$('#comment_form').remove();
$('#new_comment').show();
$('#comments').append('<%= j render(@comment) %>');
```

Everything work great. comment has appeared with no refresh page needed.

> But i got one thing i didnt want, everytime i post a new comment, the
>   comment went to the bottom of comment list (which i order the comment by created
>   at DESC). I need to refresh the page to make all comments appear properly. I wish everytime i posted a new comment, it would be at the top of comment list. How to make it happen ? Thank You very much..

[This is the image with (.append) inside create.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBong.jpg)

[This is image with (.prepend) inside create.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLqC1.jpg)

Comment: Use prepend instead of append.

Comment: In `comments/create.js.erb` don't append the new comment (use prepend). OR,  Render the `posts/_comment.html.erb` partial with `@post` as local.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#comments').prepend('<%= j render(@comment) %>');
```

I assume this will resolve your problem.

The `.prepend()` method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use `.append()`).

Comment: .prepend made the comment disappear. Need to refresh page first to make it appear.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot as you want and what is the current?

Comment: I have put the images. please take a look sir. Thank you

Comment: can you show the log the $('#comments').children().length

Comment: I'm sorry, how to get that? I'm still new on rails. Thanks

Comment: Just open the dev tool of your browser and in console panel type $('#comments').children().length and do the enter

Comment: it said "0" sir